Legacy data migration into Guidewire Cloud BC
I hope you're all doing well! I'm currently researching the process of migrating legacy billing data into Guidewire BillingCenter, and I could really use your insights. If anyone has experience with this and could share the steps or any tips, I’d be incredibly grateful!
Thanks so much in advance for your help!

This is too general of a question to be meaningfully answered on this forum. The process of migrating legacy data to any Guidewire application is incredibly complex and requires many steps. Is there a particular aspect of the data migration process you are looking for help with?

I'm looking for the high-level context. As an example:
Step1: pulling mainframe data
Step2: transform and load data using the GMT
Etc…

Legacy is something other than GW?
You have BC only? What's the source of Billing Instructions in your setup? If that's PC then the question would be, how do you migrate your policies?
If on renewal (alternative is Big Bang) then when policy is migrated to GW for renewal all the Account setup etc. should follow via regular ootb integrations.
This normally a much bigger question on how you do document bundling and processes outside of Guidewire, how do they combine legacy and Guidewire data for Portals?
Check the PMT tools for Policy migration from legacy.

There's also Billing Migration Tool for Guidewire Cloud that you could investigate.
